# Javascript array acts strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, xcode, arrays, cordova

I am passing a JSON object and an array to a Javascript function, but the array acts empty when I alert it unless I alert a specific value.

```
function myFunction(jsonObj, array){
    alert(array['item1']['name']);    //alerts "item1"
    alert(array);                     // alerts "" (not [object] as I'd expect)
    alert(array.join(''));            // alerts ""
}
```

What am I missing?

I'm developing with phonegap on xcode and also using jQuery and Jquery Mobile

Comment: Can you reproduce this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: you are not using arrays correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are using an array with string indexes. That won't work well:

```
> var array = [];
> array['foo'] = 'bar';
> array.length
0
```

Use an object instead:

```
var obj = {};
obj['foo'] = 'bar';
```

---

**Use arrays only with numeric indexes.**

Comment: Ok, I couldn't figure out how to use jsfiddle. But the link shows how the array is built up (different places in the script) http://jsfiddle.net/rks7S/2/

Comment: You're welcome :) Btw, `myList['items'][] = itemInfo1;` is not valid either. You have to do something like `myList['items'] = []; myList['items'].push(itemInfo1);`

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQuery's map function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

You can traverse all items in array or JSON Object.

**By the way**, add console.log(array) to your code and in chrome web dev env, or in firebug check it's structure.

Answer (score 0):

array can only have number as indexes , so as to use normal array functions like join

But , an associative array would be treated in the same way as a JSON object .
You can do the join in the associative array like this  :

```
var temp=[];
temp['item']='hello ';
temp['item2']='world';
var joinedString="";
for( i in temp ){
     console.log(temp[i];
     joinedString+=temp[i];
}
 alert(joinedString);   // Prints hello world
```

Just use it like a map and use a foreach loop . Normal array functions like join , length and all won't work